# Convert float day of year in datetime mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I have the following table in MySQL DB:

```
year | day_of_year
2012 | 283.813090
```

How to convert these fields in `DateTime`?

I tried:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(year, day_of_year) from tableName;
```

It returns the `Date` (`yyyy-mm-dd`)... How can I get the `Time` (hh:mm:ss)?

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: How do we decode `283.813090` to a date/time?

Comment: hmm, why would someone store in such an encoded fashion:)?

Comment: correct! @newfurniturey 283 is 283º day in year fied... and .813090 is a fraction of that day... but in other register i have in day_of_year the value 283.844016 and .844016 * 24 = 20.256384 will be a valid time? how do you got that time?

Comment: @Vidkor exec the query i got the date "2012-10-10" but i dont know how convert in time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using MySQL's [`SEC_TO_TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function (and a little math), you'll be able to get your timestamp.

The math involved would be to multiply your `day_of_year` column by the number of seconds in a day, 86400, and then mod-the result on 86400, giving you the equation `((day_of_year * 86400) % 86400)`:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((day_of_year * 86400) % 86400) AS time;
```

If I run this with the value `283.813090`, it gives me the correct time-of-day*:

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((283.813090 * 86400) % 86400) AS time;
+----------+
| time     |
+----------+
| 19:30:51 |
+----------+
```

To combine this with the actual date, you can either select them in two separate columns or use `CONCAT()` to get a real "timestamp":

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(MAKEDATE(year, day_of_year), ' ', SEC_TO_TIME((day_of_year * 86400) % 86400)) AS timestamp
FROM tableName;
```

* The math behind the time-of-day calculation is fairly straightforward. For `283.813090`, this says that there are 283 days. To calculate the *time-of-day*, we use the fractional portion and multiply by 24 (for the hours). `.813090 * 24 = 19.51416`. This says there are 19 hours; to calculate minutes, we take the fractional portion of this and multiply by 60. `.51416 * 60 = 30.8496`, which says 30 minutes. For the seconds, again, take the fractional part and multiply by 60: `.8496 * 60 = 50.976`. So, altogether we have 19 hours, 30 minutes and 50 seconds (with .976 milliseconds, which rounds up) - 19:30:51, or 7:30pm.

Comment: Rather than `(day_of_year * 86400) % 86400`, why not just `((day_of_year-floor(day_of_year))*86400` ?

Comment: @NRohler There's several ways to do the math; I could have also used `(1 - (ceiling(day_of_year) - day_of_year)) * 86400`. I used my way because it was easier to read (to me), but you could substitute your favorite/preferred method for the same results.

Comment: @newfurniturey this was the math that I was not able to do!!!! Thanks!!! a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the query I came up with:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(
                 MAKEDATE(year, day_of_year),
                 SEC_TO_TIME((1 - (round(day_of_year) - day_of_year)) * 24 * 60 * 60))
FROM tableName;
```

**What's this?**

`1 - (round(day_of_year) - day_of_year)` => getting the fractional part ( .813090 )
`24 * 60 * 60` => total seconds in 1 day = 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds

**Testing**

You can play with the query using the SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f62619/21

**Results**

These are the results with the two samples you provided in the question:

```
October, 10 2012 19:30:51+0000
October, 10 2012 20:15:23+0000
```

**References**

These are nice resources that helped me construct the query:

[12.7. Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
[How to add date or time values in MySQL](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/165-how-to-add-date-or-time-values-in-mysql/)